# changing top position for all elements of a class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple div's which have a onmouseover action which generates the top for them .It is OOTB js file so I cannot change it .Is there a way that I can change the top values of the div elements with the same class to another value after the onmouseover event has fired .SO lets say this event creates the pop up with the top 123 and I want the top to be 23 .Is it possible .

Thanks

Comment: well I know that I can use the .css property to insert the top value but the onmouseover function just rewrites it .

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about using jQuery UI to create dialogs on every mouseover event and you are trying to change the dialogs position by changing it's top property then you will need to use the dialogs position option like this:

```
$("#popup").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).dialog({
        position: [123,23]
    });
});
```

This will create a dialog with a left property of 123px and top of 23px. Alternatively, if you insist on using the css method then you could do it to the div which is wrapped around #popup when the dialog is created:

```
$(".ui-dialog").css("top", "23px");
```

For more info on the dialog position option: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

**NOTE:** This question is very ambiguous and since I can't comment yet, I have had to do a lot of guessing.. I was killing time :)